# Count occurrences of distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find a MySQL query that will display the number of occurrences of an ID value within a year.

Table:

```
a_id      year
----      ----
1        2010
1        2011
1        2012
1        2012
1        2013
1        2014
1        2015
2        2010
2        2011
2        2013
2        2014
2        2014
2        2015
3        2010
3        2010
3        2011
```

Expected output:

```
a_id    year    occurrences
----    -----   -----------
1       2010        1
1       2011        1
1       2012        2
1       2013        1
1       2014        1
1       2015        1
2       2010        1
2       2011        1
2       2013        1
2       2014        2
2       2015        1
3       2010        2
3       2011        1
```

I'm trying with the something along the lines of following sql query, but it gives me nothing like the expected output. It's the 3rd column im struggling with.

```
SELECT a__id, year, count(distinct a_id) as occurrences
FROM table1
GROUP by year
ORDER by a_id
```

How can i create that 3rd column?

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. In time, this will prove problematic.

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri has given a perfect answer, just go through it once, it seems ok according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scince you are grouping by `a_id` and `year` you of course get only 1 distinct value for group. Simply change `count(distinct a_id)` to `count(*)`.

For example you get group:

```
1        2012
1        2012
```

Notice in this group distinct a_id values is 1. But you want count of all rows in group. With `distinct` you will get 1 as occurence in all groups.

**EDIT**:

Ok, I have missed that you are grouping only by `year`, so you should group by `a_id` also. The rest of the answer stays as is. So you end up with:

```
SELECT a__id, year, count(*) as occurrences
FROM table1
GROUP by a__id, year
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following will get you what you are looking for.

```
SELECT a_id, year, count(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY a_id, year
ORDER BY a_id, year
```

Although, in previous versions, ORDER BY may have been guaranteed by MySQL, it is deprecated now.  If you want to ensure your results come back sorted, add ORDER BY.  'Future you' will thank you for it.

Comment: ORDER BY is redundant in this particular context, but otherwise fine.

Comment: How so?  Does MySQL force the ORDER BY?  I'd always rather be explicit then just assume.

Comment: Yes. It does, but no harm in a 'belt and braces' approach

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation that supports that, in cases such as this, ORDER BY is guaranteed?  Not being combative, I work in SQL Server, not MySQL, so I'm very curious.

Comment: I didn't know but actually, as of 5.6 (or possibly 5.5), 'reliance upon this behaviour' is deprecated. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html. It WAS the case way back in 5.1 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

Comment: So, it's deprecated and on it's way out.  Deprecated features are something that we need to plan for, ahead of time.  I don't tell my developers to use features that are deprecated so when you go to vNext, you don't have to go back and refactor.  We need to consider people in a year that come back to look at this answer and may be on some version that doesn't guarantee sort order.

Comment: Yes. Maybe update your answer to correct my error, and describe the reality of the situation ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a__id, year, count(*) as occurrences
FROM table1
GROUP by a__id, year
```